# Facebook iOs sdk iphone : Call from multiple viewcontroller

Tags: facebook, ios

i followed the official guide from facebook dev doc for implementing SSO from my iphone app,
but all is in the same viewcontroller who hold istance of "Facebook" class.
Now consider i want to login in first viewcontroller of one navigationcontroller and then call graph api from the third viewcontroller of the same navigationcontroller.
I think i can share the variable from one controller to another, but i wish to know if there is some "classic" ways to accomplish this. Indeed what i wish to accomplish in something like:
At the start of app i wish to login and then call graph api (or fql) wherever i need in my app.

Thx

Answer (score 10):

I just did this:

in the YourApp_AppDelegate.h

```
#import "FBConnect.h"

Facebook *facebook;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
```

In the YourApp_AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize facebook;
```

Then in your application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_FACEBOOK_API"];
```

From your viewController.h (any of them),

```
#import "YourApp_AppDelegate.h"

YourApp_AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

And then, in your viewController.m viewDidLoad function:

```
appDelegate = (YourApp_AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Now, anytime you want to refer to your Facebook singleton, just refer to it like:

```
[appDelegate.facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
```

Comment: The call is: [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:<(id<FBSessionDelegate>)]; You have to specify a delegate.

Answer (score -1):

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_FACEBOOK_API" andDelegate:self];
```

Thats how it looks like on my code :)