# Facebook Iphone application setup issues

Tags: facebook, sdk, ios4

I followed the guide on the facebook developer site, yet I'm having this same problem with my multi-view application.  I basically want to authenticate the use when they land on the home page, and then be able to pull dialog windows in other view controllers. I had hoped the initial SSO dialog would appear based on my problem, and the code I placed in the app delegate file as per the guide.

Another thread exists for this problem, but the solution wasn't accepted.  ([Facebook iOs sdk iphone : Call from multiple viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340375/facebook-ios-sdk-iphone-call-from-multiple-viewcontroller/6131138#6131138))

I tried Jeffrey's solution (since the authorization dialog wasn't popping up when the app starts up).

I get the warning:

```
  Sending 'ViewController *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FBSessionDelegate>'
```

and the app crashes. What else should i be checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least to fix your warning and crash there, I suspect you need to create a new viewcontroller class that implements the `FBSessionDelegate` protocol and pass that instead